# Would like to add login with facebook , google and Window live mail in my web application

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I have developed one asp.net web application and now i would like to add new functionality as we can see today it in many website that user can login with facebook, google and window live mail id, i don't know about anything so please help me and provide me authenticate reference to implement this in my existing application.

And how can i manage it in my existing login mechanism ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you even tried using google before asking here ?

What do you want is called "single sign on" or "openID". If you dont know a thing about this, you better use some 3rd party solution for this, for example take a look at http://www.janrain.com/products/engage

Another good project is http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/